# Linux Bash Script Date

Tags: linux, bash, date

I have created a linux bash script directory structure which is all working fine except from the date is not showing in the logfile which is created!

Here is the code for the logfile

```
touch $1/logfile.log
CURRENTDATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"`
printf "Created by: $USER\nDate/Time Created: $CURRENTDATE" > $1/logfile.log
```

The message from the command line I receive is: CURRENTDATE: Command Not Found, then when opening the logfile.log created the correct USER appears but there is no date.

Any Advise? Thanks

Comment: check your path for the date command. type ```which date``` from the cmdline to check. You may need to provide the path with your date command e.g. /bin/date

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There seems to be no direct issue with the presented code-block, however I would strongly recommend to follow up with http://www.shellcheck.net which will tell you various improvements you can make to these 3 lines. Especially follow up with : https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2059

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: @al76 Yes your right it’s /bin/date, would this mean CURRENTDATE = /bin/date ?

Comment: @GrantJamieson I would try /bin/date

Comment: See [Why does a space in a variable assignment give an error in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41748466/4154375).

Answer (score 1):

You should use "echo" not printf if you are using linux.

```
talha@DESKTOP-BCDU8TA:~$ touch logfile.log
talha@DESKTOP-BCDU8TA:~$ echo -e "Created by: $USER\nDate/Time Created:$CURRENTDATE" > logfile.log
talha@DESKTOP-BCDU8TA:~$ cat *log 
Created by: talha 
Date/Time Created: 2021-10-30 20:57:48
```

So as you can see on the code sample it worked.

Comment: We usually avoid repeat answers on Stack Overflow. But if you are going to repeat previous guidance, you need to offer more detail and explanation—which is exactly what you’ve done here. I appreciate both the explanation and the sample output; that’s useful.

Answer (score 0):

try with echo command:

```
echo -e "Created by: $USER\nDate/Time Created: $CURRENTDATE" > $1/logfile.log
```