# How to create a tokenization tool in bash script?

Tags: bash, token

I need to create a tool to tokenize an input list.
I would be providing a text file containing a list of subdomains in the following manner:

```
abc.xyc.kkk.com
hjk.pol.lll.kkk.com
...
```

And the output need to be :

```
abc
xyz
kkk
hjk
...
```

The delimiter is '`.`'

I have tried out the following code, which does not seem to be working:

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING= cat $1
IFS='.' read -ra VALUES <<< "$STRING"

## To print all values
for i in "${VALUES[@]}"; do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: Can you precisely specify the rules? Why is `.com` omitted – is it because `com` is in blacklist or simply because `com` is the last token in the current whitespace-free block? Also, I assume `….xyc.…` → `… xyz …` is a typo – you may want to fix that. Please edit your question using the grey edit button below your question.

Comment: CHeck your code at https://shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Comment: `STRING= cat $1` is a duplicate of [Why does a space in a variable assignment give an error in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748466/why-does-a-space-in-a-variable-assignment-give-an-error-in-bash), and [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash).

Comment: ...afaict, the rest of what you're referring to as "tokenization" is just splitting on a delimiter, which we also have duplicates already covering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script had some mistakes that I corrected. Now it works :

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING='
abc.xyc.kkk.com hjk.pol.lll.kkk.com
'

IFS=' ' read -d '' -a VALUES <<< "$STRING"

for i in ${VALUES[@]}; do
    echo "$i" | sed 's/\./ /g' 
done
```

Output

```
abc xyc kkk com
hjk pol lll kkk com
```

By the way, if you want to have each token in the array, instead of the entire url, you can do this :

```
#!/bin/bash

STRING='
abc.xyc.kkk.com hjk.pol.lll.kkk.com
'

IFS='.' read -d '' -a VALUES <<< "$STRING"

for i in ${VALUES[@]}; do
    echo "$i" | sed 's/\./ /g' 
done
```

Output

```
abc
xyc
kkk
com
hjk
pol
lll
kkk
com
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: `"${VALUES[@]}"`, or else it has all the bugs of `${VALUES[*]}`.

Comment: And it's much more efficient to use `${i//./ }` than `sed`.

Comment: More generally, though, a question that doesn't specify *one single error* with the shortest code that reproduces it should be closed as too-broad, not answered (or closed as duplicate, with a separate duplicate for each specific/narrower question hidden within the larger/broader question).

Answer (score 1):

Something like in `awk` can do the work:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="."; RS=" "} {$NF=""} 1'
```

Here is the test:

```
$ echo abc.xyc.kkk.com hjk.pol.lll.kkk.com |awk 'BEGIN {FS="."; RS=" "} {$NF=""} 1'
abc xyc kkk
hjk pol lll kkk
```