# Bash script no response when executing in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, variables, grep, echo

I created a bash script that will print qmb00l if the sch is 4cn.tbl, and qmb00l45 if the sch is 4cn1.tbl, but when I execute the script, there is no response in terminal. I want to print like this

Sch Name  : qmb00l

```
cd /home/fj/vanessa/Desktop
sch="$(echo -n " Sch Name  : "; grep -o '4cn.tbl\|4cn1.tbl' schmaneg.sch)"
                        if [ "$sch" = 4cn.tbl ]; then 
                            sch = "qmb00l"
                            echo $sch
                        fi
                        if [ "$sch" = 4cn1.tbl ]; then
                            sch = "qmb00l45"
                            echo $sch
                        fi
```

this is what inside the schmaneg file:

```
blah
4cn.tbl
bleh
```

I debugged but nothing happened.

Comment: Here is what inside the schmaneg file:

Comment: Please, do not use pictures. I think you want `[ "$sch" = '4cn.tbl' ]` instead of `[ "$sch" = 4cn.tbl ]`

Comment: Note that assignments don't work when you have spaces around the `=`

Comment: [Why does a space in a variable assignment give an error in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748466/why-does-a-space-in-a-variable-assignment-give-an-error-in-bash)

Comment: Also, please provide code, errors, execution transcripts, &c. **as text**. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta].

Comment: Running `bash -x yourscript` is also a good place to start in trying to figure out where in the execution of `yourscript` things first don't go according to plan.

Comment: That said, you're putting the string `Sch Name` inside your variable, and comparing it against values that _don't_ contain that string; so _of course_ it'll never match.

Comment: Also, note that `sh` and `bash` are two different shells. If you want to run your script with bash, only use `bash yourscript`, never `sh yourscript`.

Comment: Anyhow -- I'd suggest keeping the `Sch Name:` label outside of your variable's contents, and adding it only when you echo the value.

Comment: @DavidRanieri, since none of the characters in `4cn.tbl` are subject to any kind of shell parsing when used unquoted, what difference would it make?

Comment: Hi already removed the spaces between the = sign and the output is close to what I want. But how can I get this output? Sch Name : qmb00l

Comment: this is the revised code but still I don't get what I want.                     cd /home/fj/vanessa/Desktop
                    sch="$(echo -n " Sch Name  : "; grep -o '4cn.tbl\|4cn1.tbl' schmaneg.sch)"

                        if [ "$sch"=4cn.tbl ]; then 
                            sch = "qmb00l"
                            echo $sch
                        fi

                        if [ "$sch"=4cn1.tbl ]; then
                            sch="qmb00l45"
                            echo $sch
                        fi

Comment: @vane0121.vb With this code, `$sch` will never be either "4cn.tbl" or "4cn1.tbl". Instead, it will be  " Sch Name  : 4cn.tbl" or " Sch Name  : 4cn1.tbl", and these are not the same as what you are testing for. As Charles Duffy suggested, it'd be better not to include the laben in the variable's value.

Answer (score 2):

After you run this line

```
sch="$(echo -n " Sch Name  : "; grep -o '4cn.tbl\|4cn1.tbl' schmaneg.sch)"
```

$sch contains " Sch Name. : 4cn.tbl"

Then these comparisons never succeed: `[ "$sch" = 4cn.tbl ]` or `[ "$sch" = 4cn1.tbl ]`

Keep the details that are meant for output until you actually need to output them:

```bash
cd /home/fj/vanessa/Desktop

case "$(grep -o '4cn.tbl\|4cn1.tbl' schmaneg.sch)" in
    "4cn.tbl")  sch=qmb00l    ;;
    "4cn1.tbl") sch=qmb00l45  ;;
    *)          sch="unknown" ;;
esac

echo " Sch Name  : $sch"
```